# How do WYSIWYG editors insert images?

Tags: javascript, php

I have been looking into WYSIWYG editors recently and I understand how they work and how they post the data to PHP and then store it in a database. There is one critical part that I don't understand, and that is how do they insert images and then post them, especially if there is multiple images being posted. How is that done? I have looked through Google for help but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It simply upload the desired images on the server, and then include it using HTML tag (<img src="path/to/my/image/img.jpg">)

Comment: They add an image tag with the src attribute pointed at an image. It works exactly the same as any other tag. If you are asking about images from the user's computer - not all of them provide that capability but the ones that do, just upload the image to the server and the src then points to the uploaded file.

Comment: but how? The only way i can see of doing that is to have a seperate input field, and have multiple for multiple images, i dont understand.

Comment: It just creates as many <img> HTML tag as you need just like you would do if you were writing the HTML to display those images yourself